# How do I explicitly set a table name?

Tags: typeorm

I can't find anything in the documentation about this, and strangely also not here - is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can find information as to how to explicitly set a table name here.

https://typeorm.io/#/decorator-reference/entity

```
@Entity("users")
export class User {
```